# SwiftUI: How to move MapPin after an API call?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I'm trying to use the new Map component of SwiftUI. So far, so good but now, I'm struggling to update the MapPins on a map after an API response. (in order to update the pins with a map move).
I've used [TinyNetworking](https://github.com/objcio/tiny-networking) for the network call, and the call is working fine, but then MapPins are not updated and I don't understand why.

Here is some code:

The network call:

```
@ObservedObject var places = Resource(endpoint: getPlaces())
```

The Map declaration:

```
 var locations: [Location]
 Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region,
     interactionModes: .all,
     showsUserLocation: true,
     userTrackingMode: $trackingMode,
     annotationItems: locations) { location -> MapPin in
     MapPin(coordinate: location.coordinate, tint: .red)

 }
```

Place struct:

```
struct Place: Codable {
  let title: String
  let coordinates: Coordinates
}
```

Location struct:

```
struct Location: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let title: String
  let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

And here is where I try to make the connection:

```
MapView(followUser: $followUser, locations: convertPlacesToLocation(newPlaces: places))

private func convertPlacesToLocation(newPlaces: Resource<[Place]>) -> [Location] {
    var locations: [Location] = []
    if let values = newPlaces.value {
        for place in values {
            locations.append(Location(title: place.title, coordinate: .init(latitude: place.coordinates.lat, longitude: place.coordinates.lon)))
        }
    }        
    return locations
}
```

The `convertPlacesToLocation` is indeed called twice: when first loading the map, before the return of the network call, and after the return of the call, where the values are correct.
But the MapPin are not updated ...

Any ideas?

Here is the code to make the network call and reload places:

```
final class Resource<A>: ObservableObject {
    let endpoint: Endpoint<A>

    @Published var value: A?

    init(endpoint: Endpoint<A>) {
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        reload()
    }
    
    func reload() {
        URLSession.shared.load(endpoint) { result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.value = try? result.get()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show where/how do you update `places`?

Comment: Ok, I found it: it was because I was using "@State" in my MapView to transfer the locations ... but I don't understand